# Show message for few intervals after save and then redirect to another page

Tags: asp.net, message

I have two asp pages. When i save the records i want the message to be displayed for few seconds and then redirect to thhe second page. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Just my personal opinion: I hate when websites do that! Either the message is important, then give me time to read or don't show it to me at all instead of wasting my time. What I'm saying is: please try to find a way to include the information in the second page.

Comment: @Twinkles Yes that's right so do I, it's better to show message in the second page.

Comment: How you want to do this using C# or javascript ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad Anything that would work well.

Comment: @Twinkles If you can suggest me a solution on second page than do that too please